# Load CSV from secured S3 bucket into Neo4j running in docker

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, neo4j

Is it possible to use load csv to load data into Neo4j running on a docker container where the csv file is in a secured S3 bucket? It works fine if I copy the file locally onto the docker container.

I keep getting a 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed' error.

The neo config shows: dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

My code is Python (3.6) using py2neo (3.1.2).

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://s3-my-region.amazonaws.com/some-secured-
bucket/somefile.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ','
MERGE (person:Person {id: row.id})
ON CREATE SET person.first_name = row.first_name
, person.last_name = row.last_name
, person.email = row.email
, person.mobile_phone = row.mobile_phone
, person.business_phone = row.business_phone
, person.business_address = row.business_address
ON MATCH SET person.first_name = row.first_name
, person.last_name = row.last_name
, person.email = row.email
, person.mobile_phone = row.mobile_phone
, person.business_phone = row.business_phone
, person.business_address = row.business_address
```

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you also comment the line `dbms.directories.import=import` which force the csv file to be in that `import `directory`? and don't forget to restart the database after having changed the config file

Comment: If the url is publicly available then yes... not sure if `LOAD CSV` can handle any authorization

Comment: Thank you both for your help ... I am not allowed to make the dbms.directories.import change myself ... have to wait for our systems guys to make it ... but I will post the outcome.

Comment: The outcome is that commenting out     dbms.directories.import=import     had no obvious affect ... but I thank you again for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a time-limited signed URL on S3 and you don't need to make the file public.

see here for an example

https://advancedweb.hu/2018/10/30/s3_signed_urls/

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j “LOAD CSV“ can work with http/https urls, such as:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myfile/loadcsv/file.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 3
RETURN line

The following configuration need to be changed

1. the S3 folder needs to be **open to public**
2. in neo4j.conf, set
   **dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true**
3. in neo4j.conf, comment out or delete **dbms.directories.import=import**
4. make sure firewall is **not blocking neo4j ports** [7474, 7473, 7687]

Comment: Yo don't seem to be able to do this on AWS ... which means LOAD CSV is not tenable.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use tools like `s3fs` to map your bucket as a local file system, so you can read the files directly. Only IAM access is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [@dz902](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902036/dz902) comment - this is not an option in docker container, because if you try to map `/var/lib/neo4j/import` on your s3 bucket using `s3fs` it will failed in error

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/neo4j/import': Input/output error
```

That is because `neo4j` inside the container operates and creates it's folders with different user (neo4j, uid,gid=7474).
There is an option how to run neo4j with another user, but still you cannot use root for this purpose in neo4j case.
More details on that [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/running-docker-as-nonroot-user/)

If someone have some solutions or ideas how to make this possible (I mean to map the `/var/lib/neo4j/import` folder to S3 bucket) - please give me your thoughts